# Finding the max month of a year

Tags: python, datetime, counter, monthcalendar

#### Test Code:

```
import calendar
from collections import Counter
dates = (
    '2017-05-01 11:45:35',
    '2017-06-01 11:45:35',
    '2017-06-01 11:45:35',
    '2017-07-01 11:45:35',
)
city_file = [{'Start Time': d} for d in dates]

c = Counter((calendar.month_name[int(month['Start Time'][5:7])] for month in city_file))

print(c)
```

can someone explain the code

```
 c = Counter((calendar.month_name[int(month['Start Time'][5:7])] for month in city_file))
```

especially the part, if i enter anything other than 5:7 it gives an error message.

```
month['Start Time][5:7]
```

desired output :

count of months example
January 12
feb 13

Comment: desired output :

count of months example January 12 feb 13

Answer (score 1):

Well you can evaluate that step by step:

```
[d[5:7] for d in dates] #extract month from date string
#['05', '06', '06', '07']
[int(d[5:7]) for d in dates] #extract month from date string and convert to int
#[5, 6, 6, 7]
calendar.month_name[:] #get all month names
['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
[calendar.month_name[int(d[5:7])] for d in dates] #get month names that match month in dates
#['May', 'June', 'June', 'July']
```

And once you figure out this flow you need to look at [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: is there and esy way to do this?

Comment: Your code works, why would you need it to be _easier_?

Answer (score 0):

`Start Time` contains the `dates` values.

Given the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, the range `[5:7]` is the month value.

Answer (score 0):

Your month variable is a dictionary. By using `month['Start Time']` you are accessing the dictionary with the `'Start Time'` key and returning the string of your time. The `[5:7]` part is slicing the string you get out of `month['Start Time]` from the character starting at index 5 and ending before index 7. This [5:7] correlates to the month of your string. You are then taking the string of your month and converting it to an integer: `int(month['Start Time'][5:7])`. You then have another object `calendar.month_name` that gives the name of the month for the key you pass to it. You do this for each `month` in `city_file`. That creates a generator object (you can think of it as a list) and passes it to the Counter object. The Counter object then takes all values from the generator and counts how many times they occur.